# How to make fake labels

Tags: cross-referencing, labels

I have a .tex document that contains some references to non-existing labels.
For example, it may have `\ref*{some:string}`, but no `\label{some:string}`.
This results in printing double question-marks `??` when generating the PDF.
These references used to point to a super-large appendix which I'm not including in this short version of the document. Still, I would like to be able to print the correct section numbering instead of `??`.

So, I made a command that creates an empty equation that contains only the missing label and gives it the desired tag, so that I can link label strings to the correct section numbers.

```
\newcommand{\dummylabel}[2]{\begin{equation*}\tag{#2}\label{#1}\end{equation*}}
```

and at some point of my document I have a list of such `\dummylabel`s, like so:

```
\dummylabel{some:string1}{A.1}
\dummylabel{some:string2}{C}
...
```

However, this has the side-effect of printing empty equations that are numbered (although I use the starred equations environment), which is something I don't want.

So, is there a way to hide these empty equations?
Or, is there another way to create labels for those kinds of references **and** manually give them a tag/numbering, so that when the PDF is generated it will print that tag instead of `??`?

Note that these references are starred (`\ref*{...}`), so no hyperlink is actually created, which is good.

Comment: The packages [xr](https://ctan.org/pkg/xr) and [xr-hyper](https://ctan.org/pkg/xr-hyper) provide means for importing cross-referencing-data from other documents as long as these documents' .aux-files are available.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to manually define the reference, of course.

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\dummylabel}[2]{\def\@currentlabel{#2}\label{#1}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\dummylabel{some:string1}{A.1}
\dummylabel{some:string2}{C}

Here are references to the dummy labels: \ref{some:string1} and \ref{some:string2}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you load `hyperref`, use `\ref*` in order not to make links.

Explanation: `\label{foo}` makes `foo` refer to the current value of `\@currentlabel`; usually it is `\refstepcounter` that sets `\@currentlabel`, but one can set it to whatever one desires.

*Caveat.* The `\dummylabel` commands should go after `\begin{document}`, because in the preamble the `.aux` file is not available for writing.

You can as well place `\dummylabel` at the bottom, just before `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 2):

I solve the same kind of problem with a hack by @Ulrike Fischer at [comp.text.tex](http://compgroups.net/comp.text.tex/undefined-labels/1921232). It's the commented part on the code below. I define another command to keep the original `\ref`, and to have the possibility to add extra content if the label doesn't exist

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{xparse}
\makeatletter
\NewDocumentCommand{\checkref}{mmO{\ref{#1}}}{\@ifundefined{r@#1}{#2}{#3}}
%\AtBeginDocument{\let\Oriref\ref
%   \renewcommand\ref[1]{%
%       \@ifundefined{r@#1}
%       {no label #1}
%       {ref of #1: \Oriref{#1}}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \section{one}\label{testyes}
    \ref{testyes}
    
    \ref{testno}
    
    
    \checkref{testyes}{NO}
    \checkref{testyes}{NO}[YES]
    
    \checkref{testno}{NO}[YES]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried it, but my document wouldn't compile. It was giving an error for references that target labels with underscores, like `\ref*{some_string}`.

Comment: No error with the `\checkref` macro. If you tried the commented part, the error comes from the two calls to `#1` outside any macro.

Comment: You can code `{no label \texttt{\detokenize{#1}}}{ref of \texttt{\detokenize{#1}}: \Oriref{#1}}` to avoid the error.